# Laravel multiauth redirection problem after authentication

Tags: laravel

I have three different guard with different login page

all working great but there is issue after login

E.g.
There are three Auth:

1. Default(web)
2. branch
3. agent

I logged in into agent account firs time and I logged out

when I enter credentials of branch it redirects to agent login page and when I go back to branch, voila its already logged-in

However it does not happen on first attempt of login right after opening window

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see here [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be great if you could add some code to explain what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was just cup of tee
here you go.......!

I modified attemptLogin() method in each auth's login controller

```
   protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
   {
     if($this->guard()->attempt($this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')))
     {
       return redirect()
       ->intended(route('agent.dashboard'))
       ->with('success','You are Logged!');
     }
    }
```

in case you get following error

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::attemptLogin()
```

add following on top of controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```